# How to calculate points on a line which is perpendicular to another line in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, drawing, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I'm writing code in Swift and I want to draw CAShapeLayers with BezierPaths as it's presented in the image below.

How can I calculate **C** & **D** points if points A & B are known, distance between A & B is known, and length between points C & D is also known? Also, B is exactly mid-way between C & D.

[image]

After C and D points are calculated, a line between them would be drawn using `UIBezierPath` like this:

```
let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: Cx, y: Cy))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: Dx, y: Dy))
layer.path = path.cgPath
```

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Not sure if you are saying you know A, B and the distance between them, or just the distance between them.  If the latter you'll not able to calculate absolute C & D, only their position relative to A or B.

Comment: and is B exactly mid-way between C & D?  It appears to be but it's not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: This isn’t really a Swift, Bezier path, or shape layer problem. It’s a math problem. I gave the answer in math terms. The other poster also gave you a swift implementation of that math, but it’s still really a math problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the question. I know (position of) A & B and distance between them. And yes, B is exactly mid-way between C & D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the math that I would use :)

First you can calculate the angle in the Cartesian plane from A to B:

```
theta_AB = atan2(By-Ay, Bx-Ax)
```

The angle of the perpendicular line CD is just theta + pi/2

```
theta_CD = theta_AB + pi/2
```

Then assume that `d` is the known distance between C and D.

Then you have:

```
Cx = Bx + cos(theta_CD) * d/2
Cy = By + sin(theta_CD) * d/2
Dx = Bx - cos(theta_CD) * d/2
Dy = By - sin(theta_CD) * d/2
```

So putting it all together with (hopefully) correct Swift syntax, you'd have:

```
let theta_AB = atan2(By-Ay, Bx-Ax);
let theta_CD = theta_AB + Double.pi/2.0;
let Cx = Bx + cos(theta_CD) * d/2;
let Cy = By + sin(theta_CD) * d/2;
let Dx = Bx - cos(theta_CD) * d/2;
let Dy = By - sin(theta_CD) * d/2;
let C : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: Cx, y: Cy);
let D : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: Dx, y: Dy);
```

Or something like that

Comment: Ok, you posted your answer while I was still sketching out mine. I think we came up with the same solution, but you beat me to it, and even provided Swift code, so you get my vote. (Although I am inclined to skip the Swift implementation and let the OP figure that out.)

Comment: Thanks a lot... it works like a charm. There are few answers and are all correct (for which I'm grateful) this is the simplest so I'll mark this answer as the accepted.

Answer (score 3):

This is a math question. It really doesn't matter which language but I will post the Swift solution.

To figure out the angle from another point and the point with a certain angle and distance you will need those helpers:

```
extension CGPoint {

    func angle(from location: CGPoint) -> Double {
        let deltaY = location.y - y
        let deltaX = location.x - x
        let angle = atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / .pi
        return angle
        // if you need the angle reversing y directon
        // return angle < 0 ? abs(angle) : 360 - angle
    }

    func moving(distance: Double, at angle: Double) -> CGPoint {
        .init(
            x: x + distance * __cospi(angle/180),
            y: y + distance * __sinpi(angle/180)
        )
    }
}
```

---

```
let pointA: CGPoint = .zero
let pointB: CGPoint = .init(x: 100, y: 100)

let angleAfromB = pointA.angle(from: pointB)  // 45
let angleBfromA = pointB.angle(from: pointA)  // 225

let pointE = pointA.moving(distance: 1, at: 0)     // {x 1 y 0}
let pointF = pointA.moving(distance: 1, at: 90)    // {x 0 y 1}
let pointG = pointA.moving(distance: 1, at: 180)   // {x -1 y 0}
let pointH = pointA.moving(distance: 1, at: 270)   // {x 0 y -1}

let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: pointA)
path.addLine(to: pointB)
path.close()
path.stroke()

let pointC = pointB.moving(distance: 50, at: angleAfromB + 90)
let pointD = pointB.moving(distance: 50, at: angleAfromB - 90)
let pathCD = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: pointC)
path.addLine(to: pointD)
path.close()
path.stroke()
```

[image]

Comment: This solution is also good, thanks. Only slightly more complex. This answer solves that particular case from the image in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can figure this out with algebra and the Pythagorean theorem, or trig.

Trig seems easier. Here is my off-the-cuff attempt to solve the problem using trig (not tested):

Let’s call point A’s coordinates (Ax,Ay) and B’s coordinates (Bx,By)

The angle between your line segment AB and the horizontal would be

```
theta = atan2(By-Ay, Bx-Ax)
```

The angle between line segment BD and the vertical line that drops from B would be `theta + pi/2`. (Swift’s trig libraries use radians, and pi/2 radians is 90°, or an angle perpendicular to the original angle.) Let’s call the perpendicular angle theta2.

Let’s call the length of your line segment CD L. The length of line segments BD and BC will both be half of that, or L/2.

The change in y from your point B to point D would be:

```
deltaY = L/2 • cos(theta2)
```

The change in x from your point B to point D would be

```
deltaX = L/2 • sin(theta2)
```

The coordinates of point D would be

```
Dx = Bx + deltaX
Dy = By + deltaY
```

The coordinates of point C would be

```
Cx = Bx - deltaX
Cy = By - deltaY
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. I think it's the same solution as the answer below so this could be also marked as accepted answer.